# how to delete a string from SQLite database in android?

Tags: java, android, sqlite

Hi I am new to android development. I want delete a string from the database. How.How do i do that?Please help.Below is my code. I am trying delete s string from database when press presses a button.

this is my databse helper class:

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;

public class DbHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {
    static String DATABASE_NAME="userdata";
    public static final String TABLE_NAME="user";
    public static final String KEY_FNAME="fname";
    public static final String KEY_ID="id";
    public DbHelper(Context context) {
        super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, 1);

    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        String CREATE_TABLE="CREATE TABLE "+TABLE_NAME+" ("+KEY_ID+" INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, "+KEY_FNAME+" TEXT)";
        db.execSQL(CREATE_TABLE);

    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS "+TABLE_NAME);
        onCreate(db);

    }
}
```

I want to delete a string from database.

This is what I am doing to delete the string from an activity.

```
    public void delete(String del){
    SQLiteDatabase dataBase = mHelper.getWritableDatabase();
    String[] whereArgs = new String[] { del };
    dataBase.delete(
            DbHelper.TABLE_NAME,
            DbHelper.KEY_FNAME + "=?"
                    +whereArgs, null);
    mHelper.close();
}
```

But i see it executes the above  method app crashes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two options:

1. Remove the question mark on the second argument of the `delete` method

   ```
   public void delete(String del) {
       SQLiteDatabase dataBase = mHelper.getWritableDatabase();
       String[] whereArgs = new String[] { del };
       dataBase.delete(
           DbHelper.TABLE_NAME,
           DbHelper.KEY_FNAME + "="
               +whereArgs, null);
       mHelper.close();
   }
   ```
2. Move `whereArgs` to the third argument as @hfan suggested

   ```
   public void delete(String del) {
       SQLiteDatabase dataBase = mHelper.getWritableDatabase();
       String[] whereArgs = new String[] { del };
       dataBase.delete(
           DbHelper.TABLE_NAME,
           DbHelper.KEY_FNAME + "=?",
           whereArgs);
       mHelper.close();
   }
   ```

Answer (score 0):

Put whereArgs as the last argument in the delete() method.

```
dataBase.delete(
        DbHelper.TABLE_NAME,
        DbHelper.KEY_FNAME,
                whereArgs);
```

Comment: The method delete(String, String, String[]) in the type SQLiteDatabase is not applicable for the arguments (String, String)..I see this